# Failed To Establish New Connection MAX Retry Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a script for a web scraper using Selenium on Google Chrome. However I am receiving error:

> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>   urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: 
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', >port=53051): Max retries exceeded with url: >/session/54df0082f43bf3d90fa9623057c3cf53/elements (Caused by >NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))

This is my code so far concerning using selenium and webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Specifying incognito mode as you launch your browser[OPTIONAL]
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

# Create new Instance of Chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/emmanuelyamoah/Downloads/chromedriver-2', chrome_options=option)

# Go to desired website
browser.get("https://github.com/sonyemman")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    # Wait until the final element [Avatar link] is loaded.
    # Assumption: If Avatar link is loaded, the whole page would be relatively loaded because it is among
    # the last things to be loaded.
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='avatar width-full rounded-2']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error with your code, it is a problem that you have made too many that website, I highly recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium), since it will make sure that each request to the website comes from a different machine.

Comment: How would I be able to use the Zelenium library to fix my issue?

Comment: What happens is that the website is bloquing the requests from your computer (I am assuming that it is not bloquing from all devices), zalenium handles different ”computers” for each request